# Program to write a simple product delivery code

Tags: python

It will ask like, "Do you want to buy a product y/n". If `y` then it will get your device date and delivered after 2 days. Means if run program on Tuesday, the output will be "Order will be delivered on Thursday". But there's a twist, this company doesn't deliver products on Sunday.

So if you are running the program on Friday, the output should come, "Order will be delivered on Monday".

```
import datetime

weekDays = (
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
    "Sunday"
)

todaydate = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
getweek = todaydate.weekday()
w = weekDays[getweek]

print("Do you want to buy a product y/n")
s = input()

while (-1):
    if (s == 'y'):
        if (w == 'Sunday'):
            a = todaydate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            b = a.weekday()
            c = weekDays[b]
            print("Your order will be delivered on", c)
            break
    elif (s == 'y'):
        if (w != 'Sunday'):
            print("Your order will be delivered on", w)
    elif (s == 'n'):
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        break
```

I tried this code but it's not even running.

Comment: You don't need paranthesis around the `if`s and `while` in python

Answer (score 1):

You could use this;

```
if buying_day in ['Thursday', 'Friday']: 
    delivery_day = 'Monday'
else: 
    delivery_date = todaydate + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
    delivery_day = delivery_date.weekday()

print('Your item will be delivered on', delivery_day)
```

I couldn't resist correcting your code, sorry;

```
# nothing else than this;
while True:
    s = input("Do you want to buy a product y/n")

    if s == 'y':
        todaydate = datetime.date.today()
        today = todaydate.weekday()

        if today in ['Thursday', 'Friday']: 
            delivery_day = 'Monday'
        else: 
            delivery_date = todaydate + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
            delivery_day = delivery_date.weekday()

        print('Your item will be delivered on', delivery_day)
        
    elif s == 'n'):
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by preventing getweek to have a value higher then 6(that's sunday). So just do the following

```
w = weekDays[getweek % 6] // and you can remove sunday from the list
```

Sunday will now become monday.

Also you probably want to put the `input` inside the loop, otherwise, once you said yes you will get an infinite loop.

```
while True:
    s = input("Do you want to buy a product y/n\n")

    if s == 'y':
        print("Your order will be delivered on", w)
    elif s == 'n':
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The script works! He prints the output of your variable "s" that is equal to an empty string "".

```
print(s) # ''
```

So the else estatement is chosed and your programs break the loop.

If you are trying to iterate forever first you need to use a "continue" inside the loop. Then you should use "while(True)" or something like that but works with "-1" too.

Anything different from "0" or "None" will be converted to true but legibility is a good thing.

Your if s == 'y' are matching in the first call so the elif s == 'y' will never works.

```
import datetime

weekDays  = ("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")
todaydate = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days = 2)
getweek   = todaydate.weekday()
w = weekDays[getweek]

print("Do you want to buy a product y/n")

while(True):
    print(w)
    s = input()
    if(s == 'y'):
        if(w == 'Sunday'):
            a = todaydate + datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
            b = a.weekday()
            c = weekDays[b]
            print("Your order will be delivered on", c)
            continue
        else:
            print("Your order will be delivered on", w)
    elif(s == 'n'):
        continue
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
```